# find coordinates are of a parallelogram

Tags: permutations, analytic-geometry

if the coordinates are `(1, 2)  (4, 3) (1, 0) (-2, -1)`, how can we can find whether it is of a parallelogram or not

Comment: One tip: first make a graph. Because when you are  shuffling coordinates, you may be connecting diagonals which doesn't lead to the desired shape...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without drawing a graph, we know if it is a parallelogram using the following :

Four distinct points $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)$ are the vertices of a parallelogram if and only if either
$$\frac{a+c}{2}=\frac{e+g}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{b+d}{2}=\frac{f+h}{2}$$
or$$\frac{a+e}{2}=\frac{c+g}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{b+f}{2}=\frac{d+h}{2}$$or$$\frac{a+g}{2}=\frac{e+c}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{b+h}{2}=\frac{f+d}{2}$$holds.